# Работа со словарем

Tags: python

Необходимо реализовать добавление нового продукта и его цены пользователем в словарь. Я попытался объявить сам словарь, но как добавить в него новый продукт я не знаю. Как это сделать?

```
dict = {
  "Банан": 200, 
  "Груша": 100, 
  "Манго": 300,
  "Арбуз": 150,
  "Киви": 300,
  "Апельсин": 150,
  "Молоко": 120,
  "Колбаса": 440,
  "Хлеб": 50,
  "Вода": 90,
} 


total = sum(dict.values())
print(total)
```

Comment: `dict[key] = value`

Comment: Спросить у пользователя наименование нового продукта. Спросить у пользователя цену нового продукта. Поместить данные о новом продукте в словарь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В python в словарь запись можно добавить так

```
dict[key] = value
```

Поэтому:

```py
name = input("Название: ");
price = input("Цена: ");

dict[name] = int(price);
```